# Why 'am start PACKAGE' cannot launch some apps and shows an error?

Tags: system-error, command-line

I keep having an error trying to start some apps using *am start* command. It works for many, but for some apps I get the same error mentioned below:

```
#adb shell am start com.amazon.venezia
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.amazon.venezia }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.amazon.venezia }

#adb shell am start com.whatsapp
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.whatsapp }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.whatsapp }
```

Comment: Just to add on. I can manually tap on the apps and turn them on but in using $ adb shell am start _____ gives that same error for many apps. It seems to give the error when the Package Name is COM.____ but if it is something else the ADB START works

Comment: I thought it had to do if the Package Name started with COM. but that doesn't seem to be related. Same error for many apps

Comment: In case you need to start an app  using only its package name, you can use this alternative: `monkey -p PACKAGE 1`

Comment: So the command would be something like $adb monkey -p com.whatsapp   ?? I tried also $adb start monkey -p com.whatsapp  .....I can't seem to get that command right :/ (syntax wise). Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: The command would be `adb shell monkey -p PACKAGE 1`.  This trick used to work well. Now it is acting funny in Android 6.0.1 for some reason.

Comment: IT WORKED! Your the best...  but it opens the app but gives this output (what does it mean):  Events injected: 1
## Network stats: elapsed time=118ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 118ms not connected)

Comment: You can read about monkey here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html. It is  a trick I learned from some answer on [so] sometime ago.

Comment: Interesting stuff, thank you for sharing it was educational. Do you why the orignal error above was even appearing and why this command is needed instead? It's just wierd it isn't for all apps but only about half of them experience this.

Comment: I do not know. I would have provided a formal answer if I knew the reason. Time doesn't permit me to find out the reason either. Sorry!

Comment: No worries was just wondering and really appriciate your help. If you don't mind me asking? I read the link but don't fully under the "event-count". You showed above that I should use "1. "I guess the -p allows it to run one package name but what does the "1" mean and increasing it by more do anything? I can't seem to see any difference when testing.

Comment: `am start` isn't working for those apps because they don't have a "default" Activity that handles `action.MAIN`.  You could try to inspect their manifest file (inside the APK) to determine a specific activity to start.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.whatsapp/.HomeActivity
```

Comment: While this might answer the question "How to start WA via ADB", that was not what the OP asked (though it might be implicated). Could you please [edit] your answer and add some explanation?